# Select only Columns without Null values in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have 20 columns in my table....

How can I select only columns that don't have null value

```
col1 col2 col3
20    12   null
```

Desired output

```
col1 col2 
20    12
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this. The list of columns to select is hard-coded in your `SELECT` statement. You can use `WHERE` and `HAVING` to filter out rows, but you can't change the columns dynamically.

Comment: There are so many questions here having same concern as yours.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627938/oracle-finding-columns-with-only-null-values
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219870/how-to-select-columns-from-a-table-which-have-non-null-values
Any of these helps?

Comment: The question is not well formed.  Do you wish to select only columns which have ALWAYS (this means: IN EVERY RECORD) NOT NULL values?  Or do you wish to select only columns which have the NOT NULL attribute on DDL?

Comment: Not NOT NULL attribute... The columns may or may not have values.. I need to select only columns with values

Answer (score 3):

The semantics of SQL don't allow this - every SQL query includes a projection, by which you specify what columns you want in the output.

Unless you run the query twice, you can't know ahead of time what the results will be. In fact, even if you run the query twice, the results may change in between (unless you run it in serializable mode).

In other words, the question doesn't make a lot of sense.

On the other hand, if your requirement is to simply hide the column when displayed to the user, that's an entirely different question - one for which the answer does not lie in SQL, but in your presentation logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the table's metadata and check for the columns which are defined NOT NULL and create a select query with only those columns.