# how to select not null values column dynamically?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I created a table like below. I want to select only NOT NULL column dynamically like(NO, NAME,SAL_1). No need to select SAL,SAL_2.

Note: Initially I don't know the columns values.

```
create table sample(no integer,name varchar(20),sal integer,sal_1 integer,sal_2 integer);
insert into sample(name,sal_1) values('aaa',10);
insert into sample(no,name,sal_1) values(20,'',20);
insert into sample(sal_1) values(30);

select * from sample;
```

data like below

> ```
> NO        NAME    SAL   SAL_1 SAL_2
> 20       (null)   (null)  20  (null)
> (null)    (null)  (null)  30  (null)
> (null)    aaa     (null)  10  (null)
> ```

Expected op:

```
NO       NAME   SAL_1
20      (null)  20
(null)  (null)  30
(null)  aaa     10
```

Comment: Select NO ,Name,SAL_1 from sample

Comment: @Velu: So total no. of columns, i.e. 5 columns, in your table will be fixed, right ?

Comment: @KeyurPanchal ..No columns is not fixed.In my table have 30 columns for sample purpose i given only 5.

Comment: probably repeat: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523338/select-only-columns-without-null-values-in-oracle

Answer (score 0):

The following query generates the query you want to execute through some dynamic SQL procedure.

Unfortunately I don't know well the Oracle syntax, the following is in PostgreSQL, but I guess you'll only have to change `string_agg` with the pertinent Oracle function catenating strings.

```
WITH columns (c) AS (
  SELECT 'no' WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sample WHERE no IS NOT NULL)
  UNION
  SELECT 'name' WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sample WHERE name IS NOT NULL)
  UNION
  SELECT 'sal' WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sample WHERE sal IS NOT NULL)
  UNION
  SELECT 'sal_1' WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sample WHERE sal_1 IS NOT NULL)
  UNION
  SELECT 'sal_2' WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sample WHERE sal_2 IS NOT NULL)
)
SELECT 'SELECT ' || string_agg(c, ', ') || ' FROM sample;' FROM columns;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

I have checked and exactly match your output.

```
select no,"NAME",sal_1 from sample having count(sal_1)>0  group by 
sal_1,name,no order by name desc
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This,

select * from sample where nvl(NO,0)> 0 and nvl(length(NAME),0)>0 and nvl(SAL_1,0)>0