# Exclude columns with no data in them

Tags: sql, oracle

Using Oracle with TOAD.

I have a table that looks something like this (columns 2 and 4 are empty and columns 1, 3 and 5 have data in them):

```
column_1   column_2   column_3   column_4    column_5
a1                    b1                     c1
a2                    b2                     c2
a3                    b3                     c3
a4                    b4                     c4
```

I would like to do a simple select that excludes columns with no data in them (= columns 2 and 4) or ain other words, to select only the columns that have data in them.
Is there a select command such as `SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE columns ARE NOT NULL` (this is pseudo code just for clarification for my problem).

The result should look like this:

```
column_1   column_3   column_5
a1         b1         c1
a2         b2         c2
a3         b3         c3
a4         b4         c4
```

Comment: In standard SQL, a query returns a *fixed* set of columns. What you ask for requires dynamic SQL.

Comment: I agree with @GMB [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61405867/exclude-columns-with-no-data-in-them#comment108627429_61405867) I think the only way to do it is in two stages. First find which columns only have null value, then perform a SQL query that does not contain those columns. Of-course you could write PL/SQL code that would combine the two operations.

Comment: @GMB @Abra I'm trying something like `SELECT * FROM  test_table WHERE 'column' is null;` but that does not return anything (no error message either). Is this code close to what I should do to find the empty columns? And **is an empty column equal to a column that only has null values?**

Comment: [Oracle: Finding Columns with only null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627938/oracle-finding-columns-with-only-null-values)

Comment: `SELECT count(*) FROM test_table WHERE 'column' is not null` If the query returns 0 (zero), then all values of 'column' in `test_table` are null. Note that an empty column is equal to a column that only has null values.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a three-step approach but it is largely tedious but do-able in sqlplus

1)First identify the columns which are empty

2)Define the headers without those columns

3)define the body without those columns

```
    WITH data AS
        (
               SELECT '1' a,
                      ''  b ,
                      2   c ,
                      ''  d,
                      5   e
               FROM   dual
               UNION ALL
               SELECT '7' a,
                      ''  b ,
                      2   c ,
                      ''  d,
                      6
               FROM   dual
               UNION ALL
               SELECT '3' a,
                      ''  b ,
                      3   c ,
                      ''  d,
                      7
               FROM   dual
               UNION ALL
               SELECT '4' a,
                      ''  b ,
                      3   c ,
                      ''  d,
                      8
               FROM   dual
               UNION ALL
               SELECT '5' a,
                      ''  b ,
                      2   c ,
                      ''  d,
                      9
               FROM   dual),d1 AS
        (
                 SELECT   First_value(a) ignore nulls over (PARTITION BY a ORDER BY ROWNUM) ca,
                          first_value(b) ignore nulls over (PARTITION BY b ORDER BY ROWNUM) cb,
                          first_value(c) ignore nulls over (PARTITION BY c ORDER BY ROWNUM) cc,
                          first_value(d) ignore nulls over (PARTITION BY d ORDER BY ROWNUM) cd,
                          first_value(e) ignore nulls over (PARTITION BY e ORDER BY ROWNUM) ce
                 FROM     data
                 WHERE    ROWNUM=1 ),
        d2 as (SELECT 0 rw,
               CASE
                      WHEN ca IS NOT NULL THEN 'a'
                      ELSE ''
               END
                      ||chr(9)
                      ||
               CASE
                      WHEN cb IS NOT NULL THEN 'b'
                      ELSE ''
               END
                      ||chr(9)
                      ||
               CASE
                      WHEN cc IS NOT NULL THEN 'c'
                      ELSE ''
               END
                      ||chr(9)
                      ||
               CASE
                      WHEN cd IS NOT NULL THEN 'd'
                      ELSE ''
               END
                      ||chr(9)
                      ||
               CASE
                      WHEN ce IS NOT NULL THEN 'e'
                      ELSE ''
               END as DATA1
        FROM   d1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
               rownum rw,
               a
                      ||chr(9)
                      ||b
                      ||chr(9)
                      ||c
                      ||chr(9)
                      ||d
                      ||chr(9)
                      ||e
        FROM   data)
        select /*ansiconsole*/ DATA1
        from d2 order by rw asc;
```

Comment: Hi thanks! Do you know any ways to do it in **a way that automatically identifies the columns which are empty**?

Comment: if First_value(a) ignore nulls over (PARTITION BY a ORDER BY ROWNUM) is null then the column is null